# Find a basis for the range of a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Supposed $T(v) = Av$ and say I have a matrix like this:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -2 \\ 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 7 & -6 \end{bmatrix}$$

and I want to find the basis for the range.

Is this right?

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -2 \\ 2 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 7 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & -5 & 4 \\ 0 & 5 & -4 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -2 \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{-4}{5} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \frac{-2}{5} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{-4}{5} \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

question, how do you know the first two columns are linearly independent? In short, why does then taking the first two columns from the original matrix the basis for the range of T?

The basis I think is: $(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 2 & -1 & 7 \end{bmatrix})$. Is this right?

Most importantly, how do you know the first two rows in the reduced row form are linearly independent?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is sound. Elementary row operations don't chance the linearly independentness of columns, so from the reduced row echelon form you arrived at you can see the two first columns are linearly independent, while the third can (allegedly)  be written as a sum of the two first. In the original matrix then $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 7\end{bmatrix}$ must be linearly independent.

These vectors are in the range of $T$ since $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 & 0  \\ 1 & 7 & 6 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$
and 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & -1 \\ 2 & -1 & 0  \\ 1 & 7 & 6 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 7\end{bmatrix}$$
So since we know the range is 2-dimensional they must span the range.

That being said, there is a small mistake in your calculation as the original matrix is invertible.

Comment: Does my calculation imply that the original matrix is not invertible somehow?

Comment: Yes, since elementary row operations don't change the linear independentness of the columns, the original matrix is invertible if and only if the reduced echelon matrix is invertible, which it is clearly not, right?

Comment: How do you know the original matrix is invertible and the reduced one is not? How do you know so quickly?

Comment: The reduced version the last column is clearly a linear combination of the two others, so the range must be two dimensional hence not invertible. In the original matrix I calculated the determinant to be non-zero  (I got -60) hence it is invertible.

Comment: Hmmm I wonder where I went wrong....

Comment: I got 0 for the original matrix as the determinant.

Comment: Here is a site that calculates the reduced row echelon form and tell's you the steps to get there http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi?c=rref

Comment: wow thanks + I'm just an idiot and had a typo in my original matrix.